# Port forwarding to a python UDP server not working

Tags: python, sockets, server, udp, portforwarding

I've a simple UDP python server set up on my computer which I'd like to access from over the internet. I want to open a port and forward data to my python server but I can't get it to open for some reason. I use this site which says the port is closed despite having port forwarded. https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/.

[Here's a screenshot of my router settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0d06.png)

I can access the server locally.

```
import socket
localIP     = "192.168.1.106"
localPort   = 8080
bufferSize  = 1024



msgFromServer       = "Hello UDP Client"

bytesToSend         = str.encode(msgFromServer)
UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPServerSocket.bind((localIP, localPort))
print("UDP server up and listening")

while(True):

    bytesAddressPair = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)

    message = bytesAddressPair[0]

    address = bytesAddressPair[1]

    clientMsg = "Message from Client:{}".format(message)
    clientIP  = "Client IP Address:{}".format(address)

    print(clientMsg)
    print(clientIP)

    UDPServerSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, address)
```

[Website says it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMci8.png)

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is not your computer's local IP address. Also you are redirecting from port 49152 to 8080.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address. 127.0.0.1 from the perspective of your computer is your computer. 127.0.0.1 from the perspective of the router is the router itself. You need to a) port forward to the IP address of your computer in the LAN (i.e. something like 192.168.1.XXX) and b) actually listen on this IP (or simply 0.0.0.0) and not 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, sorry. I changed the screenshot and code. It still doesn't work. I tried a bunch of different things and forgot to change it back.

Comment: @nagyl Sorry, I know that's not my computer's IP address, I changed the code and screenshot. Is it not okay to redirect from 49152 to 8080?

Comment: It is okay, but you will have to connect to that port from outside of your network. I suggest using the same port for the port range (8080). Also please attach your client's code too, I think you might have an error there.

Comment: @nagyl I haven't even written a client yet, because I haven't gotten the port forwarding to work. Surely I don't need a client to see if the port is open, since I'm using the website?

Comment: @GodtyckligFysiker Okay, try connecting to the same IP (make sure it's your external IP address) and port 49152 with the website while your application is running, is that work?

Comment: @nagyl No, it doesn't. What do you think could be wrong?

Comment: @GodtyckligFysiker Does your app runs while you test it? These port scanners may not see the port as open if there is nothing to connect to. Make sure 192.168.1.106 is your computer's local address. Make sure your PC's firewall does allow python to use port 8080. How do you know you can access it locally if you have no client? I would change the external port to 8080 just to make sure.

Comment: @nagyl Yes, its running. I've tried turning off my firewall and I've tried creating a new rule to let all traffic through port 8080. I don't know how to allow python to use it, is that necessary? Okay, I do have a client but I haven't used it over the internet so it should be irrelevant. I've tried many different ports.

Comment: @nagyl That website apparently only searched for TCP. So the server was working the entire time, facepalm. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GodtyckligFysiker glad you sorted out